# Simple question on basis for induced topology

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a set and $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of real functions $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I want to prove that $\mathcal{B}=\{W(x,A, \varepsilon\}|x \in X, A \subset \mathcal{F} \text{ finite },\varepsilon>0 \}$ where $W(x,A,\varepsilon)=\{ y\in X\mid |f(y)-f(x)| < \varepsilon \forall f \in A\}$ is a basis for the induced topology on X (i.e the smallest topology in X that makes the functions from X to $\mathbb{R}$ continuous).

I know that if  $X$ is a set $Y_i, i \in I$ topological spaces and $\mathcal{B}_i $ are bases for $Y_i$ then $\mathcal{B}'=\{ {\cap}_{i=1}^{n} f_i^{-1}(B_i)|B_i \in \mathcal{B}_i, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a basis for X (with the induced topology).

I tried using that with $\mathcal{B}_i=\{(f_i(x)- \varepsilon,f_i(x)+ \varepsilon)| \varepsilon>0,x\in \mathbb{R} \}$ :

$ {\cap}_{i=1}^{n} f_i^{-1}(B_i)= \{y \in X: |f_i(y)-f_i(x_i)|< \varepsilon_i \forall i=1,...,n\} $ since each $B_i=(f_i(x_i)- \varepsilon_i,f_i(x_i)+ \varepsilon_i)$ (trying to show that $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{B}'$) but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: When you say "$A \subset \mathcal{F} finite$", do you mean "$A \subset \mathcal{F}, |A| \text{ is finite}$"?  \$A \subset \mathcal{F}, |A| \text{ is finite}\$

Comment: Yes, A is a finite subset of $\mathcal{F}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be any topology that makes all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ continuous. Also, let $\mathcal{T}_w$ be the induced topology on $X$ by $\mathcal{F}$.

Then for each $x \in X$, $\varepsilon>0$ and $f \in \mathcal{F}$ we have that

$$W(x,\{f\},\varepsilon) = f^{-1}[(f(x)-\varepsilon, f(x)+\varepsilon)]$$ by definition, and as open intervals are open in $\Bbb R$ and $f$ is continuous, $W(x,\{f\},\varepsilon) \in \mathcal{T}$.

Conversely, if a topology $\mathcal{T}$ contains all sets of the form $W(x,\{f\},\varepsilon)$, then all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ are continuous: let $O$ be open in $\Bbb R$ and $f \in \mathcal{F}$, then $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $\mathcal{T}$: let $x \in f^{-1}[O]$, then $f(x) \in O$ and so for some $\varepsilon >0$, $f(x)-\varepsilon, f(x)+\varepsilon) \subseteq O$. But then $W(x,\{f\},\varepsilon) \subseteq f^{-1}[O]$ and so $x$ is a $\mathcal{T}$-interior point of $f^{-1}[O]$.  As $x$ was arbitrary, $f^{-1}[O] \in \mathcal{T}$ for all open $O$ and all $f \in \mathcal{F}$.

Together this shows that $\mathcal{S}= \{W(x, \{f\}, \varepsilon)\mid x \in X, \varepsilon>0, f \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is a subbase (i.e. generating set) for $\mathcal{T}_w$. And as

$$W(x, \mathcal{A},\varepsilon) = \bigcap_{f \in \mathcal{F}} W(x,\{f\},\varepsilon\}$$

the proposed set is the base generated by $\mathcal{S}$ and so a base for $\mathcal{T}_w$. QED

---

It's also not too hard to check that the proposed base satisfies the two conditions to be a base for *some* topology. It's clear that every $x$ is covered by $W(x,\{f\},1)$ for any $f \in \mathcal{F}$, so that part is trivial, and if $y \in W(x_1, \mathcal{A}_1, r_1) \cap W(x_2, \mathcal{A}_2, r_2)$ we know that for all $f \in \mathcal{A}_1$, $|f(z) - f(x_1)| < r_1$ and also for all $g \in \mathcal{A}_2$ we have $|f(z) - f(x_2)| < r_2$. Consider the finitely many $f(y) \in (f(x_1)-r, f(x_1)+r)$, where $f$ ranges over $\mathcal{A}_1$; as the interval is open, we can find some $0 < r_1' < r_1$ so that the all intervals around these  $f(y)$ with radius $r'_1$ are still inside $(f(x_1)-r, f(x_1)+r)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{A}_1$; similarly we can find $0 < r'_2 < r_2$ that works for all $f(y), f \in \mathcal{A}_2$; now define $r' = \min(r_1', r_2')>0$ and note that now we have $$W(y, \mathcal{A}_1 \cup \mathcal{A}_2, r') \subseteq W(x_1, \mathcal{A}_1, r_1) \cap W(x_2, \mathcal{A}_2, r_2)$$ so the final axiom to be a base is satisfied.

As $\mathcal{S}$, the subbase for $\mathcal{T}_w$ is already included in this base, as we saw, the generated topology by this base is exactly $\mathcal{T}_w$.

Comment: $\mathcal{S} $ is a subbasis for $\mathcal{T}_w$ so that the family of finite intersections of $\mathcal{S}$ let's call it $\mathcal{B}'$ is a basis for $\mathcal{T}_w$. It is clear that $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{B}'$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the one we want but how do we show the inverse inclusion? (since taking intersections in $\mathcal{S}$ might change the $x$ and $\varepsilon$ in $W(x,\{f\},\varepsilon)$)

Comment: @WalterWhite It's enough for local bases at $x$ for every fixed $x$, so we can keep the $x$ constant and take minima of the finitely many $\varepsilon_i$ if needed.

Comment: @WalterWhite I showed directly that it is a base at the end now.

Comment: I think $r'$ should be $\min\{r_1-r_1',r_2-r_2 '\}$

Comment: @WalterWhite no, read carefully. We could write an explicit formula for $r’$ if we’d like, but not that one. I rather rely on the known openness of intervals to shorten the write-up.

Comment: You already wrote an explicit formula for $r'$ which is $\min\{ r_1',r_2' \}$

Comment: @WalterWhite that is to take care of intersection functions.

Comment: @HennoBransma I know, what I said is that instead of writing $\min\{r_1',r_2' \}$ I think you should written $\min \{r_1-r_1',r_2-r_2' \}$ (after doing the calculations that seemed to work). I didn't disagree on the fact that you found the $r_1',r_2'$ using the openness of intervals

Comment: @WalterWhite no, the $r’_i$ are already chosen as a minimum of finitely many radii. They already work as is, almost. The extra min is to take care of any $$ that are in both $\mathcal{A}_i$.

Comment: How is the $r_1'$ for example chosen as a minimum of finitely many radii? I thought that your argument was that since $|f(y)-f(x_1)|<r_1, \exists 0<r_1'<r_1: |f(y)-f(x_1)|<r_1'$ and that is how $r_1'$ was defined. Did I understand something wrong?

Comment: @WalterWhite $f(y) \in B(f(x_1, r_1)$ for all $f \in \mathcal{A}_1$. So we find $r_1(f) >0$ so that $B(f(y), r_1(f)) \subseteq B(f(x_1), r_1)$ for each $f \in \mathcal{A}_1$, and then let $r'_1 = \min\{r_1(f) \mid f \in \mathcal{A}_1\}$. Ditto for $r'_2$ and $f \in \mathcal{A}-2$ and $B(f(x_2,r_2)$. Then $r'= \min(r'_1. r'_2)>0$ so that the same $r'$ works for all of $\mathcal{A_1} \cup \mathcal{A}_2$ and $y$. Clear?